# How to know when an <input> element has been deselected using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to perform some validation once two different fields have values in them. My current code for one of the input fields looks like this:

```
$("#project1").focusout(function () {
    if (projLoc && projLoc.value) {
        projEntered = true;
        console.log("project entered in row " + row);
        if (projEntered && taskEntered) {
            Validate();
        }
    }
    else {
        projEntered = false;
    }
});
```

I'd like to change the value of the boolean `projEntered` to true when a value is in the text input field and the input field has been deselected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.blur()` from http://api.jquery.com/blur/ .

```js
$( "#target" ).blur(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1">
  <input type="text" value="Field 2">
</form>
```

As you can see from the snippet, `blur()` is called when `Field 1` loses focus

Comment: or $(...).change if you want to make sure the field has changed after blurring out

Comment: Thanks! The .blur listener worked. I also had to check and see if there was content in the field by changing [if (projLoc && projLoc.value)] to [if (document.getElementById("project1") != "")].

Answer (score 0):

If the id of an input element is defined as *"target"*, then the following code using vanilla Javascript will do the job for you:

```js
let yourElement = document.getElementById("target");

yourElement.onblur = () => console.log("hi!");
```